# Can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, django, heroku

My `Procfile` contains

```
web: gunicorn chn_parking.wsgi
```

Why I am getting this error?

> Can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I am trying to deploy an app on Heroku. All was fine...

[image]

Comment: Maybe the manage.py file doesn't exists?

Comment: All was fine until what?

Comment: until doing the migrations. the site is there in the app on heroku, but without migrating things on DB can't finish the site

Comment: What do you mean by "doing the migrations"? Generating them, e.g. with `manage.py makemigrations`? Or running them on Heroku, e.g. with `heroku run python manage.py migrate`? `manage.py` does exist, and is tracked by Git, right?

Comment: heroku run python manage.py migrate

Comment: Do you get this error _when_ running that command? Or are you seeing it in your main Heroku logs, coming from the web dyno?

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug on heroku. I build the app with python 3.7 and this is why gives me the error.
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/issues/728

What is odd, is the fact that earlier today, i pushed another app on heroku with 3.7 and it worked like a charm!

Comment: Are you entirely sure that this is the problem? I don't see how that bug would cause the error you're asking about.

Comment: Check the link. I am sure. I checked the log also from heroku on their site

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your site is called `chn_parking`, your `Procfile` should probably contain

```
web: gunicorn chn_parking.wsgi
```

instead of referencing `chn_parking.settings`.

Comment: thank you! you are right! i changed that! but i still have the same issue. :(

Comment: I've tried even with web: python src/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT --noreload

Comment: Why would you do that? `manage.py runserver` should never be used in production. Did you get the same error about not being able to find `manage.py`?

Comment: What about the question I asked above? "`manage.py` does exist, and is tracked by Git, right?" It's in the root of your repository, right beside your `Procfile`?

Comment: @Cohen, if you run `heroku run bash` you'll get a shell on a one-off dyno. What does `ls manage.py` give from that shell?

Comment: So it looks like that file _doesn't_ exist on Heroku. On your local machine, what does `git ls-files manage.py` in the root of your project give?